# please can someone help me with (or where) i can find dataset about Student e-learning habit before and during Covid-19?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for detailed data about Student e-learning habit before and during Covid-19

Comment: Have a look at this link [Dataset of Vietnamese student's learning habits during COVID-19](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S235234092030576X)